# How to host a web service in MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-services, asp.net-mvc-3

How can I use a web service in mvc3? Where should I include the web service? Completely new to that...Help please.

Comment: What do you mean by 'use web service'? Are you wanting to call a web service from your client, your server app or are you wanting to host a web service?

Comment: you don't need to "include the web service". either expose your MVC operations via REST or don't use MVC at all - use WCF.

Comment: I just rolled back the edit from today because "host" means something totally different from what the OP had in mind.

Comment: @John Saunders: the OP's comment above says "I want to host a web service"

Comment: @Neil: did the OP give any indication that he knew what the term "host" meant? Note also that none of the answers said anything about hosting.

Comment: @John: I'm not going to assume you or the answers were inside the OP's head. And that the OP's comment (and RPM1984's) was wrong. People often answer a question based on the title alone.

Answer (score 3):

In latest versions of VS you can click here:
[image]

In opened window you will be able to enter service address and do required configuration.

You can place your service references in any project. Id suggest to create a separate project and hold them there.

Answer (score 2):

They made it hard to find the add Web Reference functions in later versions of VS, seeming to try and make us use fully blown WCF hosted services instead... But you can still do it.

Right click on the `Service References` folder and click on `Add a new Reference` then click on `Advanced` and then there is another button to add a Web Service in that window.

Comment: I'd hardly call it hard to find. It's accessible when you right click on the project, or References and choose 'Add Service Reference'. Unless you're the type of user who needs giant buttons...

Comment: It's not intuitive, and was changed without easily accessible documentation from VS 2008 to 2010 - so it is 'hard' to find if you don;t know where to look.

Comment: So it seems like this lets you add a "Reference" to a web service, but the button in the advanced tab brings me to a dialog where I could browse for a web service already in my solution... so what would I do before that to create a web service in my MVC3 solution?

Answer (score 1):

I help maintain the Open Source [ServiceStack web services framework](http://www.servicestack.net) that has a NuGet **[MVC PowerPack](http://www.servicestack.net/mvc-powerpack/)** letting you trivially add Web Service Functionality to any MVC web application.

Out of the box, without any config or code-gen, ServiceStack automatically provides REST XML, JSON, JSV, CSV and SOAP web services. Here are a couple live demos that show you how to easily create web services with just C# (and no Config):

1. [Hello World Tutorial](http://www.servicestack.net/ServiceStack.Hello/)
2. [Northwind Database Web Services](http://www.servicestack.net/ServiceStack.Northwind/)
3. [GitHub-like REST files explorer](http://www.servicestack.net/RestFiles/#!files)

#### Edit added MV3 + ServiceStack Demo

The [SocialBootstrapApi](https://github.com/ServiceStack/SocialBootstrapApi) Demo project is a functional MVC3 + ServiceStack + Twitter Bootstrap + Backbone SPA website which also has a live copy of the repo deployed on AppHarbor at: http://bootstrapapi.apphb.com