# design pattern for adding a web service in ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, web-services, dependency-injection

Firstly - I'm not asking this question [How to host a web service in MVC3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488661/how-to-include-a-web-service-in-mvc3) I know where the button is :-)

I'm trying to find an example of best practices of how to use the new DI / Common Service Locator framework in order to make web service calls (and code dependent on web service calls) testable. I've no experience of using NInject or the like - is that the way to go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what is the best practice but I think you can do this with Windsor's WCF facility (Ninject has a [WCF extension](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.wcf) as well). Register your service, then set your dependency resolver and let MVC's dependency resolver to do the hard work, constructor injection for example:

Register your service:

```
container = new WindsorContainer().AddFacility<WcfFacility>();

container.Register(Component
    .For<IService>()
    .On(WcfEndpoint.FromConfiguration("...")))
    .LifeStyle.Transient);
```

Set dependency resolver:

```
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new WindsorDependencyResolver(container));
```

Then MVC3's new dependency resolver should be able to inject your service proxy into the constructor, for example:

```
public HomeController(IService service)
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Pretty much the same way one deals with any external depenency -- wrap it up in an interface, make the controller take an instance of the interface as a constructor parameter. Implementation-wise, you can handle things a number of ways, we have typically made the service wrapper take the service as a dependency and let structuremap worry about lifecycle. Not horribly familiar with NInject so I'm not sure if there is a better way there but I'd suspect they have similar capabilities.